# How can I tell from a Windows vm when a Linux server is done writing a file to a share they both can see using Samba

Tags: c#, linux, windows, samba, file-locking

We have a system running on Linux that writes two files to a Linux share.  There's a C# based file watcher running on another Windows vm that looks at the Linux share for the file.  Is there a way from the Windows side to tell when the file writing is complete? We have a few different hacks that in various way write a trigger file but I'm looking for a better solution.  We cannot write a trigger file directly from the origianl Linux app.  The output of that is not within our control.

Comment: Rename the file when you are done writing.

Comment: I think I have the same problem in that case - how do I know when it's done writing so I can rename it?  I do not have access to the app that's writing the file so I can't change what it does

Comment: Ahh - I now see you wrote that you have no control over the writing process. In that case renaming might still be useful if the file is locked during writing. (ie. the rename will fail if it is still writing). But as this is linux, the rename will probably succeed even during writing. In that case I don't know of a good solution.